# Программа не хочет работать при компилировании в exe файл. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Я прям новичок-новичок!
Нашёл скрипт питона и по гайду Ютуба перевёл его в exe файл используя pyinstaller
Дело в том, что скрипт через консоль запускается и прекрасно работает отображая прогресс в самой консоли. После перевода его в exe файл вот что пишет в консоли: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал папку bitcoin и в ней текстовик english.txt и после запуска консоль просто улетела. В ней максимально быстро выводился текст до надписи memory error, после этого у меня крашнулись все открытые приложения на пк и выскочила вот такая ошибка: Ошибка при запуске приложения 0xc00000fd

Через скрипт всё работает как надо, никаких папок и текстовиков создавать не надо!

Вот как выглядит сам код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любые сторонние файлы, использующиеся в скрипте должны находиться в папке с дистрибутивом. Она является корневой, если в скрипте вы указывали относительные пути.